# Text suddenly larger at 100% zoom in Visual Studio 2019/2022

Tags: visual-studio, font-size, visual-studio-2022

For some reason, the text in the text editor of VS Community 2019/2022 suddenly gets a few points larger while the zoom remains the same, at 100%. What could be causing this? I checked the font size in the `Options` dialog but it is still at the default font size of 10. I didn't install any new extensions nor make any changes to the currently installed extensions.

Comment: Normally this is as simple as **ctrl+mouse wheel** but I'm not sure I understand the question. What do you mean by "when the zoom remains the same, at 100%"?

Comment: @J'e You can zoom in and out of the text editor making the text larger or smaller, respectively. In my case, when I opened Visual Studio, the text in the editor was larger, but the zoom value in the bottom left corner of the editor window shows 100%, which has never been changed. I always keep it at 100%. And the font size in the `Options` dialog is at the default value.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed it too, but I really can't figure out why I have this behaviour. The display settings are exactly the same between VSS 2019 & VSS 2022 (I had both windows side by side on the same screen, with the same zoom level and same font-size), but the text from VSS 2022 is rendered slightly larger than the one from VSS 2019...

**EDIT : I think it's because they changed the font-family (if you look carefully, you'll see for instance that the lower case "l" letters (like in "local") don't have the same shape between VSS 2019 & VSS 2022.**